# The summary command returned different outputs

Tags: r

I have try to follow a tutorial from R in Action in Chapter 15.7 Multiple imputation, but my outputs of `summary()` were different.
See <livebook.manning.com/book/r-in-action/chapter-15/136>

Here is the code:

```
library(mice)
data(sleep, package="VIM")
imp <- mice(sleep, seed=1234)

fit <- with(imp, lm(Dream ~ Span + Gest))
pooled <- pool(fit)
summary(pooled)
```

The outputs are supposed to be:

```
est se t df Pr(>|t|) lo 95
(Intercept) 2.58858 0.27552 9.395 52.1 8.34e-13 2.03576
Span -0.00276 0.01295 -0.213 52.9 8.32e-01 -0.02874
Gest -0.00421 0.00157 -2.671 55.6 9.91e-03 -0.00736
 hi 95 nmis fmi
(Intercept) 3.14141 NA 0.0870
Span 0.02322 4 0.0806
Gest -0.00105 4 0.0537
```

But now it comes with only:

```
term     estimate   std.error  statistic       df      p.value
1 (Intercept)  2.531560872 0.260063277  9.7344035 44.41076 1.379785e-12
2        Span -0.004478330 0.011716849 -0.3822128 55.79406 7.037555e-01
3        Gest -0.004022046 0.001481345 -2.7151303 53.29365 8.909314e-03
```

I guess the outputs are varied as same command from different functions are used, as found in:
[Linear regression in R using lm: Different summary output in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474961/linear-regression-in-r-using-lm-different-summary-output-in-a-function)

I want to have the former outputs instead of the later ones.
I am using R 4.0.2 and R studio 1.3.1091(). But I think this would not be the reason.

Comment: Where do you get "The outputs are supposed to be" from?

Comment: Thanks. I followed the book R in Action. It is in Chapter 15.7 Multiple imputation. See https://livebook.manning.com/book/r-in-action/chapter-15/136

Comment: That book is nine years old and mice is still being developed. The `summary.mipo` function has changed. Study `help("summary.mipo")`. You might be interested in `summary(pooled, conf.int = TRUE)` and `summary(pooled, type = "all")`.

Comment: Revised as suggested and got the outcomes. Thanks again!